# Arrange Function not working properly - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

ive grouped the data and summed the data with dplyr.

`data[[1]] %>% group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var)))`

I ll receive the following:

```
 Risk.Currency       sum
  <chr>             <dbl>     
 1 AED           0.000375 
 2 AUD           0.0131   
 3 BRL           0.00350  
 4 CAD           0        
 5 CHF           0.0137   
 6 CLP           0.000461 
 7 CNY           0.00501  
 8 COP           0.000134 
 9 CZK           0.0000972
10 DKK           0.00347
```

If i try to add the arrange part nothing changes with my output.

```
 data[[1]] %>% group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var))) %>% arrange(desc('sum'))
```

Can you help?

EDIT:
here a working example with mtcars which shows the problem.

i created an empty list, because in my function i have  a list of dataframes

```
 data <- list()
 y_var <- "hp"
 x_var <- "cyl"

 data[[1]] <- mtcars

 data[[1]] %>% group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var))) %>% arrange(desc('sum'))
```

thank you
Stefan

Comment: `data[[1]] %>% group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var))) %>% arrange(desc(sum))` works right?

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**
You have to use `get` in the arrange function.

#### Code

```
  sort_by <- 'sum'
  
  data[[1]] <- mtcars
  
  data[[1]] %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% 
    summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var))) %>% 
    arrange(get(sort_by)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(sum))
```

#### Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     8  2929
2     4   909
3     6   856
```

#### Data:

```
data <- list()
  y_var <- "hp"
  x_var <- "cyl"
```

Comment: Hi TarJar, unfortunately this does not help.

It only adds the Column .by_group with all of them = TRUE

Comment: Ok. Could you please `dput()` the head of your data.

Comment: Hi TarJay,

> data <- list()
> data[[1]] <- mtcars
> data[[1]] %>% group_by(!!sym(x_var)) %>% summarise(sum = sum(!!sym(y_var))) %>% arrange(desc('sum'))  

here it doenst work with mtcars either.

Thanks for you help! I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please see my edit. you have to use `get`. Before define variable on which you want to sort  `sort_by <- 'sum'`. I can't just put `desc` in arrange. But it works with a second line. Cheers.